# Using Vue or any other Front End with Asp Net Core

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core

I have to make an application for my intranet where employees will be able to check their info, chat with other departments in real time, manage all the web applications they have access to...

I thought maybe it would be better to have a decent UI as a main application instead going full out on core MVC and razor

I'm still not sure but i recall having a front end framework saves bandwith or not, should I just stick with MVC and boring JQuery or Web API + Vue ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... just because you use MVC/Razor does not mean you have to have an "ugly" or "non-decent" UI.  You can still use Vue with ASP.NET... It all depends on your requirements and parameters, really...Does your company let you choose which stack to use or are there factors outside of that? How do you plan on handling authentication, etc...? Those are the things you should be concerned with - not the UI, in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry I wanted to mean for a better user experience. Mostly showing modals and showing data without refresh. I have used AngularJS before on an old project before I knew it was outdated, hence why I wanted to try Vue 'cause it basically looks the same and much more intuitive. We mainly use .Net Framework and .Net Core. Plus the app will mostly be an API for all the other apps to get data from.

Comment: ...but you can still show modals and data without refresh using jQuery...... Sounds like you need to prototype or "proof of concept" these things to test and see for yourself.

Comment: Tbh, i'm just trying to discard jQuery 'cause seems like the new trend is that jQuery is too old for modern apps and injecting javascript directly into the html tags seems so much better for productivity

Comment: It's not like jQuery is "too old" to accomplish what you want.. It's just that jQuery itself is bloated, and it can make your code bloated. It also makes your code less legible and harder to understand overall, at a 'high level' glance. Vue/React/Angular accomplish this much more efficiently....but jQuery can most def be used in a "reactive" manner - it isn't "too old" by any stretch of the imagination. Wish you the best! At the very least test out Vue and compare it to jQuery.... thats the only way YOU will know for sure.

Comment: Yes that's it! I always found it hard to read some old jQuery functions i wrote in some applications after some time and started using AngularJS after 'cause it was much easier to understand. I already read VueJS basic documentation and i'm pretty much ready to use it even for small things rather than jQuery. Really liking the simplicity.